# Making the Calculator

Tags: c#, list, loops, while-loop, calculator

I know there's tons of way of solving this issue, i know a "dumb" way using if statements, however i've been on the path of trying to use less code, but more use of it.

```
     if(ope == "+")
        {
            result = userInput + userInput2;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

and just copy past this junk for all the operators.

I did a list, with all the operators, and thought i could check the list, if input does not equal anything in the list, repeat, until an operator is picked. (This might lead to a bug() what happens if the user writes more than 1 correct answer, will it take more from the list or first one. An example: What if user inputs +- /(haven't even come this far), both of them are in the list.

Here's an example of a code that i wrote for taking double:
an example would be "while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput));" From the code snippet, where the code won't take any string values, and repeat the code over and over until userInput is a number.

I don't know how to loop the code with a do while loop to check if the userInput has the same value as the list contain: the math operators +,-,*,/;^,% and if the user input isn't correct, repeat the code until it's correct.

My question is, How do i loop through the list, check if the input is correct, pick out the correct input and solve the equation on userInput X userInput2. Should the user pick 2 operators such as / and - Repeat loop. Pick only 1 operator.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        List<string> OperatorToUse = new List<string>();
        OperatorToUse.Add("+");
        OperatorToUse.Add("-");
        OperatorToUse.Add("/");
        OperatorToUse.Add("*");
        OperatorToUse.Add("%");
        OperatorToUse.Add("^");
       
        double userInput;
        double userInput2;
        var result;
        var ope;
             
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your first number: ");
        } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput));
           #If the answer is X, and user Input is also X. stop the Loop
               #Not working
       do
       {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Operator: ");
        } while (!OperatorToUse.Contains(Console.ReadLine(), out OperatorToUse));
                #Not working
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Operator: ");
        } while (Console.Readline(ope) == "+" || ope == "-" || ope == "/");    
         
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Second number: ");
        } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput2));

        Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
     }
```

Comment: Is the ReadLine adding a carriage return at the end? Use ReadLine().Trim() to remove it.

Comment: The readLine() is used for taking input from user, Out for passing our input to the variable.  Unsure what trim is, haven't used that function

Comment: yes i know that. please read the answer you accepted. there is an extra character at the end of what is returned by ReadLine(), it is a carriage return. Which is why your code wasnt working. If you wouldve googled what trim was, you would know. If you look at the MSDN for ReadLine() it states that it includes the carriage return at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop should look like this:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your Operator: ");
    ope = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
} while (!OperatorToUse.ContainsKey(ope));
```

In the example below, instead of List I'm using Dictionary but the idea is the same.

In order to avoid if-statements for each operator, you should use a Dictionary and add each operator as a Key and the respective math function as a Value. You can do this with a delegate as in the example. Then you just call the respective function by retrieving it from the dictionary with the selected operator like this:

> OperatorToUse[ope](userInput, userInput2)

```
internal class Program
{
    delegate double MathOperation(double a, double b);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, MathOperation> OperatorToUse = new Dictionary<string, MathOperation>();
        OperatorToUse.Add("+", (a, b) => a + b);
        OperatorToUse.Add("-", (a, b) => a - b);
        OperatorToUse.Add("/", (a, b) => a / b);
        OperatorToUse.Add("*", (a, b) => a * b);
        OperatorToUse.Add("%", (a, b) => a % b);
        OperatorToUse.Add("^", Math.Pow);

        double userInput;
        double userInput2;
        string ope = String.Empty;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your first number: ");
        } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput));
                    
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Operator: ");
            ope = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
        } while (!OperatorToUse.ContainsKey(ope));

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Second number: ");
        } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput2));

        Console.WriteLine($"{OperatorToUse[ope](userInput, userInput2)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for a late reply.

Never thought about using Dictionary, as i'm not fluent enough in the C# world. Thanks for the tips and help!

Comment: Works perfectly, and as intended. Will be looking into it more, specially how dictionary works. Feels like I've missed a very crafty code. 

Thanks a lot.